# как сделать onmousemove рабочим в E-mail письме

Tags: php, javascript, email

Есть сообщение

```
$message = ' 
   <html>
     <head>
        <title>HTML email</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"margin:0; padding:0;width:100%\">

          <tr>
             <td> <img src=\'http://www.diciss.zz.mu/img/mail/1.png\' onmouseover=\'this.src=\"http://www.diciss.zz.mu/img/mail/1_.png\";\' onmouseout=\'this.src=\"http://www.diciss.zz.mu/img/mail/1.png\";\' /></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>

          </tr>
      </table>
    </body> 
  </html>';
```

Можно ли как то добавить интерактивность к сообщению onmousemove не работает

Comment: вообще-то, насколько я понимаю, поведение в данном случае зависит целиком и полностью от возможностей и конфигурации программы, с помощью которой просматривается содержимое письма. часто это т.н. «почтовый клиент».

Comment: CSS будет работать с большой вероятностью (hover), а JS - в 99% не будет.